# Что возвращает Task<List<string>> и как работать с возвращаемым значением после?

Tags: c#, android, async-await, task

Я пишу небольшое мобильное приложение. У меня есть метод, который обрабатывает данные полученные из БД(добавляет каждую запись из БД в коллекцию `List<string>`). В конце метода я возвращаю созданную коллекцию.

```
 private async Task<List<string>> getAllEvent()
        {
            List<UserEvent> events = new List<UserEvent>();
            List<string> stringsInTable = new List<string>();
            string tenUrl;
            string temp;

            HttpResponseMessage response;
            while (stringsInTable.Count < 10)
            {
                tenUrl = "http://ссылка на сайт/контроллер";
                response = await allEvent.GetAsync(tenUrl + numberEvent);
                temp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                if(temp.Contains("Not Found"))
                {
                    break;
                }
                stringsInTable.Add(temp);
                numberEvent++;
            }
            
            //await DisplayAlert("Тест", stringsInTable.Count.ToString(), "Ок");
            return stringsInTable;
        }
```

После я хочу вывести в DisplayAlert со значением первого элемента из коллекции по нажатию кнопки, но следующий код не работает. Как я понял, вызов метода возвращает не `List<string>`, а `Task<List<string>>`, это верно ?

```
 private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> test = new List<string>();
            test =  getAllEvent().Result;
            DisplayAlert("alert",test[0],"ok");
        }
```

После я сделал обработчик нажатия кнопки асинхронным и переписал код следующим образом.

```
 private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> test = new List<string>();

            test = await getAllEvent();
            await DisplayAlert("alert",test[0],"ok");
        }
```

Теперь код работает, но я не понимаю почему. Правильно ли написан обработчик нажатия кнопки ? И где можно почитать о работе с возвращаемым значением `Task<TResult>` ?

Comment: Вот тут можно почитать про асинхронное программирование https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я попробую ответить на Ваш вопрос максимально простыми словами. Формальный ответ о том, что такое Task - можно найти [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1?view=net-6.0), например.

Итак, сначала о том, что такое Task.

Вот есть у Вас функция. При "обычном" или "синхронном" вызове функции всё просиходит так: код "доходит до места вызова функции, потом проваливается в функцию, функция выполняется, и уже потом управление возвращается на следующую строку после вызова функции".

А теперь пускай у нас есть функция, помеченная модификатором `async`. При вызове такой функции "вызов" отрабатывает мгновенно. Да - да, вы не ослышались. Вы вызвали функцию? Все хорошо. Работайте дальше. Когда функция сделает свою работу - то управление вернётся на следующую за вызовом строку.

Таким образом, у нас получается такая "событийно управляемая модель": надо что то отобразить на форме, а вызов этой штуки происходит через сеть и через полмира? - ничего, мы пошлём вызов, и можно пока на форме спокойно нажимать другие кнопки, она не "зафризится". а когда результат вернётся с другой стороны земного шара - код продолжит свою работу, и нарисует Вам этот несчастный комбобокс, уже заполненный значениями.

То есть, самыми грубыми словами, Task - это "обещание сделать работу, и когда работа будет сделана - продолжить выполнять код с того же места"

А теперь - что такое Tresult. Очень просто. Вот есть у вас void-функция. Она ничего не возвращает. Если её переделывать в асинхронную - тип с void сменится на "просто Task".

А если функция возвращает какое то значение, например, string - то при переделке на асинхронную версию она будет возвращать Task - то есть, Task, у которого еще есть и результат функции, поэтому тип этого результатат входит в декларацию функции.

Надеюсь, моё объяснение будет хотя бы в какой то мере полезно.

Comment: Я бы перефразировал последние два абзаца..очень замудрёно звучит, имхо. `Task<TResult>` - это **результат** ( `TResult`) выполнения **задачи** (`Task`). Т.е задача выполнилась - отдала результат. Тоже самое что и "метод выполнился - вернул результат".

Comment: @Aarnihauta - да, я сейчас работаю над дописыванием ответа, я включу Ваше замечание в ответ, хорошо? Кстати, я пояти уверен, что Вы можете исправлять сообщения - не стесняйтесь!

Comment: Если ничего не хотим возвращать - в сигнатуре юзаем просто `Task`, а не `void`. Хоть `void` и можно заюзать вместе с `async` - это очень нежелательно, поскольку необходим **контекст** выполнения таски: грубо говоря контекст - коробка в которой че-то там делается (выполняется метод). Про подводные камни async void - [вот тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-async-void)